# How do I automate upper case formatting for select columns in excel with VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to automate formatting keyed in text into uppercase for Columns B and C and I am having trouble in setting column targets correctly.

I found this piece of code on an excel help forum but *I know this code sets the first eight columns as the target.* So, help me correct it so that Columns B and C can be set as the target.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)  
    If Target.Column > 8 Then Exit Sub  
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler  
    Application.EnableEvents = False  
    Target.Formula = UCase(Target.Formula)  
    ErrHandler:  
    Application.EnableEvents = True  
    End Sub
```

Comment: Add a new 2nd line `If Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub` and also change `8` to `3`.

Comment: Great. I've added an answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### So, help me correct it so that Columns B and C can be set as the target.

The simplest solution is to do the following:

- Add a new 2nd line:

  ```
  If Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub
  ```
- Change `8` to `3`:

  ```
  If Target.Column > 3 Then Exit Sub
  ```

So your code is now as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 
If Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub   
If Target.Column > 3 Then Exit Sub  
On Error GoTo ErrHandler  
Application.EnableEvents = False  
Target.Formula = UCase(Target.Formula)  
ErrHandler:  
Application.EnableEvents = True  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code uses an approach to exclude columns and exit the sub when it's not the right column. You can use a different approach to name (include) the columns you want to watch like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 
if not intersect(target,Range("B:C")) = nothing then
   ' run the code
end if
end sub
```

With this approach you could also watch several non-contiguous columns with one line of code. For instance, run the code on columns B, F, and Z

```
if not intersect(target,Range("B:B", "F:F", "Z:Z")) = nothing then
```